# Is there a case for time-weighted reputation score?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Given the large number of very new or relatively inactive users that seem to be in many of the forums, it is sometimes very hard to get a true indication of the influence that someone has on UXSE over time.

Does it make sense to use a time-weighted measure of reputation score to ensure that people who have accumulated a large number of points over a very short period of time (e.g. if they asked a question that attracted a lot of attention for some reason) don't end up being overrepresented in the rankings?

This can be implemented as a 'decay factor' applied to each reputation score gained, so that you can still get the full reputation score if a question or an answer is voted up, but over time it will be reduced to a value that is at least less than 50% of the original value.

Comment: It's an interesting idea, but probably more StackExchange-wide than one specific to UX SE. There's been several posts there over the years about such a concept (but to be honest it doesn't seem like a widely popular idea) - for instance: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/327557/reputation-expiration-and-deterioration/327562

Comment: I found it interesting going back to some of the referenced duplicate questions and looking at the responses provided by Jeff Atwood and Jon Skeet (although I suspect it was in the context of StackOverflow, and wonder it also applies to UXSE): https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136059/revisiting-the-rep-cap-yes-again/136293#136293

Comment: It's more that it applies to the platform as a whole - if the practice of reputation degradation were to exist in one Stack Exchange site then there's not really (well, to my mind anyway) a reason why it shouldn't on another.